# Regressions performed by hand

Tags: machine-learning, regression, linear-regression, logistic-regression

Does anyone know where I can find linear regression (simple & multiple) examples performed by hand, polynomial and logistic regressions and where it shows how to perform them by hand? I want to practice it so I learn the math behind it better.

Any books, articles, youtube videos anyone suggests?

I've seen a couple of examples already but I get easily confused because most cases they add the error in the equation or the examples aren't related to machine learning.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming and software development questions